# How to remove out of stock items from the minicart in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, mini-cart, magento2minicart

scenario- when the user doing his shopping he added some products to the basket, that are shown in the minicart by default. But when the click on mini cart (or) when the user refresh the page i need to remove of stock items from minicart and display error msg "xxx,yyy products are removed due to out of stock" inside minicart .
is this possible?
if it is can anyone pls explain indetail.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **sales_quote_save_before** event to remove the out of stocked item from the quote place your logic in commented section

**events.xml**

```
<event name="sales_quote_save_before">
    <observer name="remove_out_of_stock_item" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Remove"/>
</event>
```

**Remove.php**

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{

        /** @var $quote \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote */
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
        $result = $quote->getAllItems();
        foreach ($result as $item) {
          // get product from item and check stock status if out of stock then delete the item else proceed
               $quote->deleteItem($item);

                }
        $quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();

    return $this;

}
```

Comment: thanku @Ghulam.M. When that event is triggered

Comment: and how can i add error message in the minicart